# Reinforcement learning SARSA algorithm decreases values over time

Tags: julia, reinforcement-learning

I am currently trying to implement the SARSA algorithm, as described in Sutton, Barto "Reinforcement Learning, An Introduction" on a gridworld with a windy upstream. (I am using the same environment as Sutton, Barto - p.130.) Basically, there are 70 fields and one can move in four directions: up, down, left or right. On some states, a wind will cause the movement to shift up one step. The reward is -1 for each timestep, where the goal has not been reached.

I implemented the environment and everything seems to be working fine. However, the learning algorithm does not seem to work. The authors of the book claim that when using certain parameters, the algorithm converges to a near optimal solution after about 150 episodes learned. This is not the case for my code (written in Julia v1.1.0)

```
g = GridWorld()
α = 0.5
γ = 1
ϵ = 0.1
Q = zeros(70,4)

for episode in 1:100000

isDone = false
S = g.start
A = eps_greedy(Q,ϵ,S)


while !isDone

    (R,isDone) = action(g,A)
    S´ = g.position

    A´ = eps_greedy(Q,ϵ,S´)

    Q[S,A] += α*(R + γ* Q[S´,A´] - Q[S,A])

    S = S´
    A = A´
end



end
```

The object g stores the current state, which gets changed according to action A when calling action(g,A).  The function eps_greedy(Q,epsilon,S) just takes a current state and chooses an epsilon-greedy action from the action-value function Q.

The problem is: The longer I train, the lower the action values, stored in Q, will get. For example, training for about 2000 episodes, the action values of the starting state are all similar at approximately -950. Training for 20000 will yield action values of around -10000.
I don't think this is supposed to happen, but I am not quite sure what causes the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't your `γ` too high, causing divergence in Q-values? Look for discount factor in [the wikipedia entry for SARSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State–action–reward–state–action). The algorithm seems correctly implemented, if your `eps_greedy` is also correct.

Comment: @hckr That actually seems to have done the trick! I thought I had tried lower values before, but at least now it works. Maybe the authors of the book I referenced actually used different parameters too, although they claimed to use gamma = 1. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: If they say undiscounted, then they used `γ=1`. There probably is some other issue in your code, maybe in `GridWorld()`?